# How to implement animation based on which direction the route is transition in react-router v4?

Tags: react-router

I have successfully implemented route transition animation with react-router v4 and react-motion. Currently I can only make transition animation in one direction. For example, I use slideLeft to transition to new page. But I would like to have slideRight when then transition is happened with goBack. Generally speaking, I would like to know how to hook animation based on back or forward status.

Answer (score 1):

v4 is still in alpha, so this answer is likely to change.

In v4 alpha 6, you can access the `history` instance through the context. One of the properties of the instance is `action`, which is the action type of the last navigation. The possible values for this are `PUSH` (forward), `POP` (back), and `REPLACE` (same place, but maybe treat it like forward for an animation).

```
const { action } = this.context.history
```

You could determine the animation direction based on whichever possible value `action` is.

The latest refactor (not actually released, but available through GitHub) of v4 removed the `history` context variable, so what I described above is no longer possible. That said, there is an [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4283) and hopefully soon a PR to add the `action` as a value that will be available through the `router` context.

```
const { action } = this.context.router.getState()
```

### Edit

Apparently because use of the forward button is also a `popstate` event, the action associated is `POP`. This makes it more difficult to know whether to animate forwards or backwards. I would probably just treat all `POP`s as back, but that's a discretionary decision.

Comment: In my case things are slightly different, as I'm targeting a mobile environment and I always use transitionTo and goBack in context.history to manually navigating user. I'm not sure if it is ok to use popstate under such circumstance.

Comment: `popstate` is a browser event which you can listen for, not something that you call. By mobile, you mean that you're using a memory history? I imagine that `PUSH` and `POP` are all you need to worry about then.